# node require json persisting across files

Tags: json, node.js, require

In one of my files, `A.js`, I call `var locations = require('./locations.json')`. I then modify locations.

Then in a different file I have the same thing `var locations = require('./locations.json')`. However instead of locations having the value of what is stored in locations.json, it now contains the changes that I made in `A.js`.

A.js

```
var locations = require('./locations.json')

function func() {
    // Changing the values stored locations
}
```

B.js

```
var locations = require('./locations.json')

console.log(locations) // prints out the changes made in A.js instead of what is in locations.json
```

Why does this happen and is there any way around it?

Comment: Well it wouldn't be very good if doing `require("./commonModule.js")` from two files created two separate `commonModule` module objects. `require` only loads modules once. The way around it is dependent on what you're doing; the easiest is likely to create a deep copy of `locations` in `func`.

Comment: so it only loads the module once across projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `require` is for module loading, and only loads a single copy of whatever you pass it, and keeps a reference to it. See http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/ for technical details.

If you do want to simply load the json file use `fs.readFileSync` instead, eg:

```
var locations = fs.readFileSync('./locations.json');
```